# You are not authorized to decode the requested integrity token while decoding play integrity token

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-play-integrity-api

I have followed all the steps outlined in https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup#integrate-into-app to add Play Integrity to my Android library. Configured the app using this library as documented as well.

Android:

```
getIntegrityManager(context).requestIntegrityToken(
    IntegrityTokenRequest.builder()
        .setCloudProjectNumber(projectNumber) // <-- from app's play console linked Google Cloud project
        .setNonce(nonce)
        .build())
```

Server:

```
DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest decodeRequest = new DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest();
decodeRequest.setIntegrityToken(token);

InputStream stream = Resources.getResource("credentials.json").openStream(); // <-- from service account
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream)
    .createScoped(PlayIntegrityScopes.PLAYINTEGRITY);
HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
GoogleClientRequestInitializer initializer = new PlayIntegrityRequestInitializer();

PlayIntegrity.Builder playIntegrity = new PlayIntegrity.Builder(
        httpTransport,
        JsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
        requestInitializer)
    .setApplicationName("<proj name>") // <-- Google cloud project associated with server
    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(initializer);
PlayIntegrity play = playIntegrity.build();
DecodeIntegrityTokenResponse response = play.v1().decodeIntegrityToken(appId, decodeRequest).execute();
```

But I am getting this exception from `decodeIntegrityToken`:

```
{
     "code" : 403,
     "errors" : [ {
          "domain" : "global",
          "message" : "You are not authorized to decode the requested integrity token.",
          "reason" : "forbidden"
      } ],
      "message" : "You are not authorized to decode the requested integrity token.",
      "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

I am able to verify roles using CLI:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy <google-cloud-project-name> \
    --flatten="bindings[].members" \
    --format='table(bindings.role)' \
    --filter="bindings.members:<service-acct-name>"
ROLE
roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that Google cloud project number I was using in the Android client (in `setCloudProjectNumber()`) was that of the app (one included in `google-services.json`) and not the one corresponding to the project associated with service account of the Google cloud project associated with the backend.